# Is there a way to enumerate rows in temporal pandas data frame according to the date of an action?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a data frame with temporal data. Each row represents a purchase of a customer. It looks similar to this:

| cli_id | date | item_purchased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017-01-01 | A |
| 2 | 2017-01-04 | C |
| 3 | 2017-01-03 | B |
| 1 | 2017-02-01 | B |
| 2 | 2017-01-31 | B |
| 3 | 2017-02-02 | A |
| 1 | 2017-02-15 | A |
| 2 | 2017-02-10 | A |
| 3 | 2017-02-16 | C |
| 2 | 2017-02-20 | B |

I would like to be able to make another column that represents the order of the purchase. This way I will be able to group by the first purchase and have the mode of first purchase, then have the mode of the second purchase, and so on.

The output would look like this:

| cli_id | date | item_purchased | purchase_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017-01-01 | A | 1 |
| 2 | 2017-01-04 | C | 1 |
| 3 | 2017-01-03 | B | 1 |
| 1 | 2017-02-01 | B | 2 |
| 2 | 2017-01-31 | B | 2 |
| 3 | 2017-02-02 | A | 2 |
| 1 | 2017-02-15 | A | 3 |
| 2 | 2017-02-10 | A | 3 |
| 3 | 2017-02-16 | C | 3 |
| 2 | 2017-02-20 | B | 4 |

Important: Not all customers have the same amount of purchases (i.e., not the same amount of rows).

So far, I have tried with for loops, but it is slow:

```
list_dates = ['2017-01-01', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-03', '2017-02-01', '2017-01-31', '2017-02-02', '2017-02-15', '2017-02-10', '2017-02-16', '2017-02-20']
list_item_purchased = ['A','C','B','B','B','A','A','A','C','B']
df = pd.DataFrame({'cli_id': list_cli_id, 'date': list_dates, 'item_purchased': list_item_purchased})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

first = True
for id in df['cli_id'].unique():
    if first:
        df_order = df[df['cli_id'] == id].sort_values(by='date').reset_index().reset_index()
    else:
        df_order = df_order.append(df[df['cli_id'] == id].sort_values(by='date').reset_index().reset_index(), ignore_index=True)
    first = False

df_order = df_order.rename(columns={"level_0": "purchase_order"}).drop('index', axis=1)
```

Is there a better (faster / more elegant) way to do that? My real data frame is much bigger than this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html).

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df= (
        df
          .join((df.sort_values(by=["cli_id", "date"])
                  .groupby("cli_id").cumcount()+1)
                  .to_frame("purchase_order"))   
    )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

   cli_id       date item_purchased  purchase_order
0       1 2017-01-01              A               1
1       2 2017-01-04              C               1
2       3 2017-01-03              B               1
3       1 2017-02-01              B               2
4       2 2017-01-31              B               2
5       3 2017-02-02              A               2
6       1 2017-02-15              A               3
7       2 2017-02-10              A               3
8       3 2017-02-16              C               3
9       2 2017-02-20              B               4
```